# Обрезать текст который не помещается по высоте

Tags: css

Подскажите, как обрезать текст, который не помещается в `div` по высоте. Пытаюсь так:

```
overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; max-height: 400px
```

Обрезается, **НО** не ставится многоточие, в чем причина?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922739/limit-text-length-to-n-lines-using-css, http://dev.mobify.com/blog/multiline-ellipsis-in-pure-css/

Answer (score 3):

Попробуй добавить : `white-space: nowrap;`